# Android studio app suddenly changes of activity

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

Im making a bluetooth app where you can turn on and off an arduino light. If i comment the setContentView, this does not happen. However, when I turn it on, it happens one of two things:
the app stops
it changes of activity

here's my code

```
package com.ainimei.remotemouse

import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket
import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_control_bluetooth_connection.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

class ControlBluetoothConnection : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        var m_myUUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
        var m_bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null
        lateinit var m_progress: ProgressDialog
        lateinit var m_bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
        var m_isConnected: Boolean = false
        lateinit var m_address: String
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard)
        onCreateExtra()
    }

    private fun onCreateExtra() {
        m_address = intent.getStringExtra(Connection.EXTRA_ADDRESS).toString()
        ConnectToDevice(this).execute()

        control_led_on.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("a") }
        control_led_off.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("b") }
        control_led_disconnect.setOnClickListener { disconnect() }
    }

    private fun sendCommand(input: String) {
        if (m_bluetoothSocket != null) {
            try{
                m_bluetoothSocket!!.outputStream.write(input.toByteArray())
            } catch(e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun disconnect() {
        if (m_bluetoothSocket != null) {
            try {
                m_bluetoothSocket!!.close()
                m_bluetoothSocket = null
                m_isConnected = false
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        finish()
        alertMessage("Disconnected Successfully", "Bluetooth")
    }

    private class ConnectToDevice(c: Context) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        private var connectSuccess: Boolean = true
        private val context: Context

        init {
            this.context = c
        }

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            m_progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Connecting...", "please wait")
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): String? {
            try {
                if (m_bluetoothSocket == null || !m_isConnected) {
                    m_bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
                    val device: BluetoothDevice = m_bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(m_address)
                    m_bluetoothSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(m_myUUID)
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery()
                    m_bluetoothSocket!!.connect()
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                connectSuccess = false
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return null
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            if (!connectSuccess) {
                //Log.i("data", "couldn't connect")
            } else {
                m_isConnected = true
            }
            m_progress.dismiss()
        }
    }

    open fun alertMessage(message: String, title: String) {
        var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle(title)
        builder.setMessage(message)
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

i tried commenting some functions, and I saw that when i commented the onCreateExtra() function, this made the layout dont appear. need help

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the crash to your question.

Comment: It's not an error. It suddenly changes of activity. That's all. The error could be solved